# On water fountains, why the blue tap is supposed to be colder than the white one?

Tags: usability, design, physical

Water fountains often propose two taps, one with cold water and one with water at ambient temperature.
In my experience the cold one is labeled with a blue color while the ambient one with white color.
Why is that and not the other way around ?

Answer (score 6):

For hot/cold combinations this is a standard to avoid confusion, specially if the faucet is in a different language or uses a different arrange:

From Wikipedia **[Tap (valve)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_(valve))**

> If separate taps are fitted, it may not be immediately clear which tap
>   is hot and which is cold. [3] The hot tap generally has a red
>   indicator while the cold tap generally has a blue or green indicator.
>   In the United States, the taps are frequently also labeled with an "H"
>   or "C". Note that in countries with Romance languages, the letters "C"
>   for hot and "F" for cold are used (from French "chaud"/Italian
>   "caldo"/Spanish "caliente" (hot) and French "froid"/Italian
>   "freddo"/Spanish "frio" (cold)). This can create confusion when
>   English speakers visit these countries or vice versa. Mixer taps may
>   have a red-blue stripe or arrows indicating which side will give hot
>   and which cold.
>
> In most countries, there is a standard arrangement of hot/cold taps.
>   For example, in the United States and many other countries, the hot
>   tap is on the left by building code requirements. Many installations
>   exist where this standard has been ignored (called "crossed
>   connections" by plumbers). Mis-assembly of some single-valve mixer
>   taps will exchange hot and cold even if the fixture has been plumbed
>   correctly.

So you have `blue=cold` / `red=hot`, which are commonly accepted cultural references and have really strong affordances.

Now, **this is just a guess**, but if you add a new variant (ambient temperature), which is neither cold nor hot, this new variant can't be blue or red. Thus, it hast to use a *neutral* color which in this case is white.

Comment: This is great reasoning. +1 for pointing out the cultural differences too!